# v-model in a nested v-for of a multidimensional array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Hi I want to create a table with the days of the selected month where you can a add an employee and mark meals you want to assign to the employee.

I almost there, I can add a row to the table and mark the meals by day but when a second row is added the same meals are marked, all the meals are binded by day if i mark a meal in a row it marks for all the rows.

Here is the code and a jsfiddle

Html

```
<div id="app">
  <span class="demonstration">Pick a month</span>
  <input type="month" v-model="month">{{month}}<br><br>
  <button @click="addEmployee()">Add a employee</button><br>
  Mark meals for the employee<br>
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="3">Name</th>
        <th :colspan="calendar.length*3">days of the month</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="3" v-for="day in calendar">{{day.date}}</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <template v-for="c in calendar">
          <th>b</th>
          <th>l</th>
          <th>d</th>
        </template>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(item, indexItem) in list" :key="indexItem">
        <td>
          <input type="text" v-model="item.name">
        </td>
        <template v-for="(day, indexDay) in item.days">
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox"  v-model="item.days[indexDay].breakfast">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox"  v-model="item.days[indexDay].lunch">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox"  v-model="item.days[indexDay].dinner">
          </td>
        </template>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Vue

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    month: '',
    list: [

    ]
  },

  computed: {
    calendar () {
      let selected = new Date(this.month)
      let daysOfMonth = new Date(selected.getFullYear(), selected.getMonth() + 1, 0)
      let days = [{}]
      for (var i = 0; i < daysOfMonth.getDate(); i++) {
        days[i] = {
          date: selected.getFullYear().toString() + '-' + (selected.getMonth() + 1).toString() + '-' + (i + 1).toString(),
          breakfast: false,
          lunch: false,
          dinner: false
        }
      }
      return days
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addEmployee () {
      let cal = []
      cal = this.calendar
      this.list.push(
        {
          name: '',
          days: cal
        }
      )
    }
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/patogalarzar/v8h0knt7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sharing the same object on every row, which means when one row is update, all the rest get updated as well.

Computed method is not the right tool here. I suggest you create a method to generate the calendar object.

```
methods: {
    createCalander (month) {
      let selected = new Date(month)
      let daysOfMonth = new Date(selected.getFullYear(), selected.getMonth() + 1, 0)
      let days = [{}]
      for (var i = 0; i < daysOfMonth.getDate(); i++) {
        days[i] = {
          date: selected.getFullYear().toString() + '-' + (selected.getMonth() + 1).toString() + '-' + (i + 1).toString(),
          breakfast: false,
          lunch: false,
          dinner: false
        }
      }
      return days
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can create the computed property using this method, passing `this.month`.

On the add employees you would be using the new method to generate the list.

```
addEmployee () {
      let cal = []
      cal = this.getCalander(this.month)
      this.list.push(
        {
          name: '',
          days: cal
        }
      )
    }
```

Now that you are not using the same object, the rows will not update together.

Your mistake was to use the same object on every row.

[I've updated the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v8h0knt7/16/)

Comment: Thanks for your help it worked now I can edit cells individually. Another question when I change the month the headers are resized but the added rows maintain their size, how can I do to resize the rows without losing the marked cells

Answer (score 0):

Change your `addEmployee` method to avoid point to same object:

```
addEmployee () {
      let cal = []
      cal = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.calendar))
      this.list.push(
        {
          name: '',
          days: cal
        }
      )
 }
```

More proper way to create a method call `getCalendar` and `let cal = this.getCalendar()`

Answer (score 0):

this is because all employees reference the same object `calendar`, you can deep copy the object, or try [this way](https://jsfiddle.net/v8h0knt7/6/)